# Show that $\mathbb Z_3\times V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_6$

Tags: group-theory

Klein's group is often referred to as the klein four group and denoted by $V$. Show that $\mathbb Z_3\times V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_6$. I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Do you know a way to write $V$ as a direct product of two groups?

Comment: Can you prove that $Z_2 \times Z_3 \cong Z_6$? The reuqired isomorphisms follows from that.

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of the klein four group?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

The klein four group is $V=\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$ therefore you are looking to show that $$\Bbb Z_3\times(\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2)\cong(\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_2)\times\Bbb Z_2 \cong\Bbb Z_6\times\Bbb Z_2\cong\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_6$$
then use properties of associativity and the fact that $\Bbb Z_6$ is isomorphic to similar groups as well.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $V\cong\mathbb Z_2 \times\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3\cong\times\mathbb Z_6$